# Deserialize generic object type

Tags: c#, generics, json.net, json-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize objects from a json. The problem is that the object's type is a generic, so I do:

```
public class MyConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject) 
        {
            JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

            if (jObject["content"] != null)
            {
                foreach (JObject t in jObject["content"])
                {
                  List<JProperty> jPropList = t.Properties()
                      .Where(attr => attr.Name.Equals("date") || attr.Name.Equals("hour"))
                      ToList();

                  if (jPropList != null)
                  {
                      for (int i = jPropList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                      {
                          if (jPropList.ElementAt(i).Name.ToString().Equals("date"))
                          {
                              dt = DateTime.Parse(jPropList.ElementAt(i).Value.ToString());
                          }
                          else if (jPropList.ElementAt(i).Name.ToString().Equals("hour"))
                          {
                              string[] horario = jPropList.ElementAt(i).Value.ToString().Split(':');

                              dt = dt.AddHours(Convert.ToUInt16(horario[0]));
                              dt = dt.AddMinutes(Convert.ToUInt16(horario[1]));
                              dt = dt.AddSeconds(Convert.ToUInt16(horario[2]));
                          }
                      }

                      t.Property("date").Remove();
                      t.Property("hour").Remove();
                    }

                    T obj = serializer.Deserialize <objectType.GenericTypeArguments[0]> (t.CreateReader());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the line

```
T obj = serializer.Deserialize < objectType.GenericTypeArguments[0] > (t.CreateReader());
```

give me the compile error message:

> "Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and
>   'Type'".

I know that

```
objectType.GenericTypeArguments[0]
```

returns me a type and it's just what I need, the Type that I can instantiate to one of classes I have.

How can I get the Type of a generic object for deserialization? How can I achieve this I need to do?

Comment: See the overloads of `Deserialize` that accept `Type` instead : https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer.htm

Comment: What's `objectType` and why aren't you using `T` there? How do you know that `objectType.GetGenericArguments[0]` is the same as `T`?

Comment: Yeah, @Aybe!! It works! Thanks!

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto **objectType** is one of the parameters of ReadJson method and it is the same type of T.